# yii CActiveForm client validation not working on some field

Tags: php, yii, client-side-validation, yii-cactiverecord

In my yii application i have a simple form that contains two fields like this:

```
<?php
                        $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                            'id' => 'message-form',
                            'enableClientValidation' => true,
                            //'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                            'clientOptions' => array(
                                'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                                'validateOnChange' => false,
                                'validateOnType' => false,
                                'errorCssClass' => 'has-error',
                                'successCssClass' => 'has-success',

                        )));
                        ?>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'subject'); ?>
                                    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'subject', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
                                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'subject', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger')); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'message'); ?>
                                    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'message', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'message')); ?>
                                    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'message', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger')); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         ......
                         //remaining of code
```

"subject" and "message" are two fields of "Notification" model. in Notification model, i have defined this rule:

```
array('subject, message', 'required')
```

my problem is validation for "subject" works but validation for "message" not works!
after submitting the form, error message of "subject" shows up but "message" does not have any error. can anyone help me solve this problem?
I use Yii 1.1.15

Comment: There is a reason for HTML attribute id "message", on your message field? Yii CActiveForm generate a specific id : modelName_fieldName, you dont need to set id (like your subject field; it dont have id). YII need those format of ids for validations and more things. Remove id on your message field and test again

Comment: Yes :) you are right. solved, thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Nice! I will post as an answed for your acceptance and close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason for HTML attribute `"id" => "message"` on your message field? Yii CActiveForm generate a specific HTML id : `modelName_fieldName` for each field.

You don't need to set id manually (like your subject field; it don't have id). Yii needs those format of ids for validations, get/post data and more things (as client/js functions).

Remove `"id" => "message"` on your message field and test again.

Answer (score 1):

in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm u can see example

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'focus'=>array($model,'firstName'),
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firstName'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstName'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'firstName'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'lastName'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lastName'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'lastName'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

i think u set enableAjaxValidation = true